# IOS splash screen disable?

Tags: ios, cordova, hide, splash-screen

I'm using `phonegap`, I want to disable the splash screen, but I want to be able to do it through `Xcode` not by editing the `phonegap` `HTML` file because the `HTML` function

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since to support 4 inches device is mandatory from 1st Feb, you must need splash screen. If you want to disable it, you will need to put black colored png file with required dimensions. But you must have those files in your bundle.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how come i can see some IOS apps that launch without splash screen, how do they do it ?

Comment: You download the application in your iTunes. Extract it and see for Default-568h.png. It must be there with plain black image. So, on app run, you will find there is no splash screen.